# Get Elemt By Class Name javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the border bottom color of the `.arrow_box:after`

### JavaScript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow_box:after")[0].style.borderBottomColor="blue";
```

But it doesn't work!

Here is the same example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u2jCE/)

Comment: The `getElementsByClassName` function does not support pseudo classes. You would have to use jQuery or some other library that supports this notion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change styles of pseudo elements like `:after` (and select them as well) via JS directly. And the reason why is that they are not the part of the DOM tree.

The best you can do is assign another class to the element like this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("arrow_box")[0].className = "arrow_box blue-border";

.arrow_box.blue-border:after {
    border-bottom-color: blue;
}
```